# How do I derive the second inequality from the first one?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

How do I derive the second inequality from the first one?

$(Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+ (Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \leq 0\\
\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x-y\|,\,\, \forall x, y$

Comment: The statements don't really make sense - from the first, it would seem that $L$ is a vector, which means that the second statement is meaningless.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Sorry for the confusion, I got my first equation from the derivative of $g(x)=\frac{L}{2}\|x\|_2^2-f(x)$, correct me if I have wrong notations.

Comment: I believe you should replace $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ in the first inequality with $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: The second inequality implies the first, the reverse is not true, see for example $f(x)=-x^Tx$ and $L=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging terms we can write
$$(Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+(Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) =(Ly-\nabla f(y)-Lx+\nabla f(x))^T(x-y)\\
=-L(x-y)^T(x-y)+(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y)$$
If we use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality 
$$(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y)\leq\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\|x-y\|$$
and the second inequality we have that
$$(Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+(Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) 
\leq -L\|x-y\|^2+\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\|x-y\|\\ =-\Big[L\|x-y\|-\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\Big]\|x-y\|\leq 0$$